# how do you multiply a matrix to another with openMaya?

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to create a script for mirroring transforms across the yz plane in Maya.

I was able to set up a node network that gets the desired results.  I took a node at the origin with sz set to -1 and a source node from the left side (lf_grp for this test), and fed their worldMatrix attrs into a multMatrix node.  Then I passed the output (multMatrix.matrixSum) through a decompose matrix and into my destination node.

I'd really prefer to not create a bunch of nodes to do my mirroring - running a create/connect/disconnect/delete cycle every time is slow and painful... I'd rather just "math the crap out of it" through my script, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually multiply my two matrices...

Oh, I'm using the MTransformationMatrix since it handles a few things for you that the MMatrix does not - like rotation order (at least from what I've read...)

Thank you for any help you can give!

```
import maya.cmds as mc
import maya.OpenMaya as om

src_xfm = 'lf_grp'
mir_matrix_vals = [-1.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0,
                   0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                   0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

# get src xfm matrix
#
selList = om.MSelectionList()
selList.add(src_xfm)
mDagPath = om.MDagPath()
selList.getDagPath(0, mDagPath)

src_xfmFn = om.MFnTransform(mDagPath)
src_matrix = src_xfmFn.transformation()

# construct mir xfm matrix
#
mir_matrix = om.MTransformationMatrix()
tmp_matrix = om.MMatrix()
om.MScriptUtil().createMatrixFromList(mir_matrix_vals, tmp_matrix)
mir_matrix = om.MTransformationMatrix(tmp_matrix)

# multiply matrices to get mirrored matrix
#
dst_matrix = src_matrix * mir_matrix  # HOW DO YOU DO THIS????
```

Comment: forgot to mention that I would prefer not to use pymel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how do to it using the [openMaya api version 2](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/?guid=__py_ref_index_html).

Nowadays this is the preferred method for doing Python api work - among other things it's a lot less wordy and avoids `MScriptUtil`, which is prone to crashiness if used incorrectly.  It's also faster for most things.

This is the plain matrix multiplication:

```
from maya.api.OpemMaya import MMatrix
mat1  = MMatrix ([0.707107, 0, -0.707107, 0, 0.5, 0.707107, 0.5, 0, 0.5, -0.707107, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
mat2 = MMatrix([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 100, 200, 300, 1])
print mat1 * mat2
# (((0.707107, 0, -0.707107, 0), (0.5, 0.707107, 0.5, 0), (0.5, -0.707107, 0.5, 0), (100, 200, 300, 1)))
```

You can't directly multiply an `MTransformationMatrix` -- that class isn't a linear algebra matrix, it's an accessor for the various position, rotation, scale, shear and pivot data functions of a matrix. You use it if you want get around doing all of the concatenating math yourself on a transform node, like setting its rotation without changing its scale.

You can get the underlyying matrix from an `MTransformationMatrix` with its `asMatrix()` function.  To apply a matrix to an object :

```
from maya.api.OpenMaya import MTransformationMatrix, MGlobal, MSelectionList, MFnDagNode

sel = MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList()  # selection
dagpath = sel.getDependNode(0)          # first node
transform_node  = MFnTransform(dagpath) # MFnTransform
xfm= transform_node.transformation().asMatrix()  # matrix
new_matrix = mat1 * xfm                 # math
new_trans = MTransformationMatrix(new_matrix)
transform_node.setTransformation(new_trans)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was able to derive what I needed out of this.  I didn't actually know about the openMaya api v2... it makes much more sense to me than the original - do you happen to know if it has all of the same functionality?

Comment: It's almost the same.  It's definitely worth switching if you don't have sunk costs in existing stuff